# Cant load data to JsTree

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jstree

When I try to load a tree in this way, I get the result that is presented [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlk54.png)

```
    $.getJSON(
    '/Report/GetDepartments',
    function (data) {           
        $('#treeDiv').tree({
            data: data
        });
    }
);
```

GetDepartments controleer see as

```
 return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The result model is

```
public class TreeDepartments
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public List<TreeDepartments> children { get; set; } 
}
```

How I can load data? I read the manual and the problems should not have been. [Manual](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#Tutorial)

Comment: are you using jsTree (https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/) or jqTree(your manual link is jqTree)? your problem seem to be the json model is wrong

Comment: I use the one that I brought in the link. The model is correct, and if I do data = JSON.parse(data) nothing happens